# Prefix of suffix generation for a File in C#

Tags: c#, .net

I am writing a file generator module for an application to which a dataset and a filename is passed to generate an excel, pdf or a csv. I am thinking about passing a template filename, by which I should know if the filename requires a prefix or a suffix date, instead of assuming to add a date suffix always. I can write code to look for MM or DD or YY or YYYY and build a filename but was wondering if this could be handled better? Much appreciate your suggestions!

Comment: what regex will do here? what is the role of regex here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the sort of thing I like using the `Flags` enums for. They allow you multiple settings of the same enum, whilst retaining the benefits of using an enum. In addition, any further requirements that crop up can be accounted for by adding a new value to the enum (it must be a power of 2, so if a new value were to be added in my example, it would have the value of 4) and then creating the logic for that setting where necessary.

A quick example, using a console application:

```
public class Class1
{
    [Flags]
    private enum DateTypeRequired : byte
    {
        Prefix = 1,
        Suffix = 2
    }

    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string myFileName = "test.xls";

        var settings = DateTypeRequired.Prefix | DateTypeRequired.Suffix;

        AppendDateToFile(ref myFileName, settings);
        Console.Write(myFileName);
        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    private static void AppendDateToFile(ref string fileName, DateTypeRequired datesNeeded)
    {
        if ((datesNeeded & DateTypeRequired.Prefix) == DateTypeRequired.Prefix)
        {
            fileName = string.Concat(DateTime.Now.ToString("ddmmyyyy"), fileName);
        }

        if ((datesNeeded & DateTypeRequired.Suffix) == DateTypeRequired.Suffix)
        {
            string[] fileParts = fileName.Split(new char[]{'.'});

            fileName = string.Concat(fileParts[0],
                            string.Concat(DateTime.Now.ToString("ddmmyyyy.")), fileParts[1]);
        }
    }
}
```